# No bag entry - Cocoa

Tags: macos, cocoa, in-app-purchase

I am working on a app written in `Swift` for `Mac`. I am using XCode `6.4` on OSX `10.10.4`

I recently noticed some weird messages regarding in app purchases.
Initially when I run the app the method `request:didFailWithError` of `SKProductsRequestDelegate` is invoked as seen below

---

```
func request(request: SKRequest!, didFailWithError error: NSError!) {
    println("Failed: \(error.localizedDescription)")
}
```

This code snippet prints `Failed: No bag entry`

---

Further, to solve this I cleaned the project to remove the old binary.
When I try to execute the newly build binary from finder it says

[image]

After clicking on `Sign In` nothing happens.

---

## Questions

- What exactly is `No bag Entry`?
- Why is the alert (present in image) saying that I have already purchased the app, although I am testing in `App Store Sandbox`?

---

## Note

- The reason I am executing the App from Finder(outside Xcode) is that Mac applications are required to be executed outside Xcode for first time, so that it can fetch the Receipt from Apple Server
- Mac App store is kept `logged out` through the entire process
- This error popped up with out any reason. I am pretty much sure that something has to be done outside Xcode.

---

## Update

Apple has updated the Technical note [TN2206](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/technotes/tn2206/_index.html) on `July 27` and the change is titled

> Cover changes to linking to dynamic libraries outside of an app bundle.

I have dynamically linked openssl library in my app, I guess it has something to do with it.

Comment: Since a view days I get this strange error too! I changed nothing in my code and it worked before!

Comment: `[0] (null) @"NSLocalizedDescription" : @"No bag entry"         
[1] (null) @"NSLocalizedFailureReason" : @"Could not find key 'p2-product-offers' in bag."
`

Comment: How did you solve it ?

Comment: I did not... I found your question searching for an answer. - I get this "No bag entry" now all the times. Even inside Xcode.

Comment: Apple must have changes something!
Even an old build, which was working all the time now gives this error.
My implementation is objective-c. So it's not swift related, but platform related. Same code works on iOS for an iOS productlist.

Comment: Works on another Mac... Now I'm totally confused.

Comment: Updated post contains a link to technical note. Please check the section titled `Gatekeeper Changes in OS X v10.10.4 and Later`. This change was introduced yesterday on (July 27)

Comment: Regarding working on another Mac. Just check if it works fine after cleaning the project

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84719/discussion-between-kaunteya-and-axel-zehden).

Answer (score 0):

I've seen the "No bag entry" error passed to my `-request:didFailWithError:` method in my `SKProductsRequestDelegate` twice so far whilst developing and testing my Mac app.

The full `NSError` I've seen is:

```
Error Domain=ISErrorDomain
Code=3 "No bag entry"
UserInfo={
  NSLocalizedDescription=No bag entry,
  NSLocalizedFailureReason=Could not find key 'p2-product-offers' in bag.
}
```

I don't know what `p2-product-offers` is: this isn't a string I'm using in my app.

From searching the web, it seems that ISErrorDomain is something to do with StoreKit.

Both times I've seen this, my Internet connection has been a bit flakey.  My current guess is that this error means "the Internet connection dropped whilst StoreKit was retrieving the product information".

Comment: No. It is a server error at Apple. I compiled the same code next day( w/o cleaning) and it worked